# The form just freeze looping throught lines

Tags: vb.net, backgroundworker, freeze

I'm just stuck into something in which I can't solve it in any way. My UI freeze even with BackgroundWorker.

Regarding to my old solved problem: [VB.NET - It keep replacing itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35813594/vb-net-it-keep-replacing-itself)

'I have in a text file lines of this format:

```
word1|word2|word3
anotherword1|anotherword2
```

I'm trying to split each word one by one per every line of that file and once program detect if the richtextbox has one of these words will replace that word with the unsplitted line. Example: From word1 to word1|word2|word3'

Everything works great, but only if I'm using a file with a small set of lines to split. But I need to split a big one at once.

Here is what I have so far: http://pastebin.com/raw/k0MtPHbZ

As I said, everything works if I reduce the lines of the en.txt file and I'm kinda confused why. I would really appreciate if someone would tell me how to fix this problem.

**UPDATE:**

As you guys said look what I did:

```
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    Dim list As New List(Of String)()
    Using reader As New StreamReader(Application.StartupPath & "\en.txt")
        Dim line As String = Nothing
        Dim input = RichTextBox1.Text
        While (InlineAssignHelper(line, reader.ReadLine())) IsNot Nothing
            Dim pat = String.Format("\b({0})\b", line)
            input = Regex.Replace(input, pat, line)
        End While
        RichTextBox2.Text = input
    End Using
End Sub
```

But it still does the same. Work fine with small amount of lines. Freeze with my 500kb text file.

Comment: Post the code, not a link to the code.  `Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False` is not a solution.  Remove that line and fix the errors.  You are accessing gui controls in the background thread.

Comment: why looping 100 times. plus you are accessing text file each time and loading it

Comment: At first I was looping 100 times to get the value of integer into progressbar. I never thought about it, I'll try right now without it.

Comment: I updated the question dear friends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your background worker is still going to block on your UI thread because you're referencing UI controls in the DoWork portion. You would be better off pulling in the data on the UI thread, assigning it to a variable, and then processing that all in memory in the DoWork instead of attempting to manipulate UI from a background thread, this is going to give you grief consistently.

So in your button1.Click handler, get the input from the textbox and assign it to an instance variable. Reference that instance variable inside your DoWork for the input.

Example:

```
Public Class Form1

Private _textInput As String = String.Empty

Private Sub Button1_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    _textInput = RichTextBOx1.Text
    BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
  End Sub

 Private Shared Function InlineAssignHelper(Of T)(ByRef target As T, value As T) As T
    target = value
    Return value
End Function

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    For i = 0 To 100
         Threading.Thread.Sleep(200)
         Dim list As New List(Of String)()
        Using reader As New StreamReader(Application.StartupPath & "\en.txt")
            Dim line As String = Nothing
             While (InlineAssignHelper(line, reader.ReadLine())) IsNot Nothing
                Dim pat = String.Format("\b({0})\b", line)
                _textInput = Regex.Replace(_textInput , pat, line)
              End While
         End Using
         BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i)
     Next
  End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged
    ProgressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
    MsgBox("done")
    RichTextBox1.Text = _textInput 
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Thank you so much for spending your time trying to solve this. I think you got it right. I tried and it worked, but not at it should be.

http://prntscr.com/agj711/direct

1. It doesn't work properly
2. It doesn't freeze anymore, but you can wait three days and nothing will happen with that big text file

Comment: Maybe the best way is to split that big text file into at least 50 pieces and will work on this way...

Comment: I would step through your logic then to see why it doesn't work properly :). Glad it's keeping the UI thread free for you now though.

Comment: Yes. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Netero , if this answer solved your problem, please accept the answer :)

Comment: Sorry! I forgot, or it didn't work last time I tried since I was new back then. Thank you again for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Your Pastebin link includes the following code:

```
For i = 0 To 100
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(200)
    [...]
Next
```

At a glance, why are you putting the thread to sleep for a fifth of a second on every iteration of the for-loop?

Remove this line for starters.

Comment: This is not an answer.